# how can i detect pressing windows key with python

Tags: python, windows, keyboard

I used this one but it doesn't work for me
I really need the solution please

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "Windows":
        print("You pressed windows")
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Use is_pressed() with parameter of key you want too check

```
import keyboard 

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('Windows'): 
        print('You Pressed A Key!')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think u can use this

```
import keyboard 

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'): 
        print('You Pressed A Key!')
        break
```

Comment: i need it to detect the windows key for your code it will detect the key "q" for me i want it to detect "windows
"